# Списковое включение с условием

Tags: списки, haskell

```
function = take 10 [x | x <- [0..], x `mod` 7 == 0, x `mod` 9 == 3]
```

Что изменить, чтобы функция выдавала не просто все числа, делимые на 7 и все на 9 с остатком 3, но чтоб это происходило одновременно для всех чисел списка?

То есть только числа делимые и на 7 и на 9 с остатком 3. 
`and` и && мне не помог...

Comment: У меня ваш код ведет себя именно так: в список попадают только те числа, которые удовлетворяют одновременно обоим условиям. Например: `[21,84,147,210,273,336,399,462,525,588]`

Comment: Я наверное неправильно сформулировала вопрос, мне нужны числа которые одновременно и делятся на 7 и имеют остаток 3 при делении на 9. То есть [21, 147, 273, 399...]

Comment: не просто числа делимые либо на одно число, либо на второе, а сразу на два так сказать

Comment: Чем не подошли 84, 210, 336? Они делятся на 7 без остатка и имеют остаток 3 при делении на 9.

Comment: Упс, значит таки это правильно! в примере списка, который я должна получить эти числа не стояли, вот я и подумала, что что-то у меня не так :D Спасибо, Вам, извините , проглядела) Там оказывается нечетные, все вопрос решен))